# Error when opening a file in vim after installing Unite.vim

Tags: vim, vi, vim-plugin, unite.vim

In the picture below you can see the error I get when trying to open a file in vim after installing unite.vim plugin

I installed it by cloning the git repo and then moving the files into the same folders but under my `~/.vim/` directory.

Anyone have an idea what could be going wrong?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It *looks* like you didn't copy all the folders - since a function from `autoload/unite.vim` is not found. Perhaps read chapters 42 and 43 from http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/

Comment: This solved it, thank you for being quick! Extra kudos for noting the book chapters, really insightful, thanks.

Comment: For `vim` questions we do have a [vi.SE](http://vi.stackexchange.com) section of the website.  It might prove to be even quicker with answers.